# angularjs checkbox not getting checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in my application:

```
      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="vm.eduToEdit.test" />
      {{vm.eduToEdit.test}}
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.eduToEdit.test">
```

the value vm.eduToEdit.test is diplaying true or false, but no matter what it returns the checkboes in either input above are not checked.  I'm not sure what i'm missing, i thought i shouldn't use ng-model so then I tried ng-checked, but neither has worked so far.

EDIT:
I tried the below, but same result:

```
       <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="vm.eduToEdit.test" /> - 
       <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checking" /> - 
       {{vm.eduToEdit.test}}
       {{checking}}
```

In my controller i have:

```
    vm.eduToEdit.test = true;
    $scope.checking = true;
```

When I view the page, true is written out, but i never see it checked.

Below is my controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

myModule.controller('EducationController', ["$scope", "bootstrappedData", EducationController]);

function EducationController($scope, bootstrappedData) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.shoppingCart = bootstrappedData.shoppingCart;
    vm.eduToEdit = {};

    vm.EditEducation = function (applicantEducationId, educationTypeId) {
        var owl = $(".owl-carousel");

        var eduFound = $.grep(this.shoppingCart, function (h) {
            return h.ApplicantEducationId === applicantEducationId;
        });
        vm.eduToEdit = eduFound[0];
        vm.eduToEdit.formattedAttendEnd = vm.ConvertToDate(vm.eduToEdit.AttendEnd);
        vm.eduToEdit.formattedAttendStart = vm.ConvertToDate(vm.eduToEdit.AttendStart);
        vm.eduToEdit.formattedGraduationDate = vm.ConvertToDate(vm.eduToEdit.GraduationDate);

        vm.eduToEdit.test = true;
        $scope.checking = true;

        switch (educationTypeId) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [1, 50]);
                break;
            case 5:
                owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [3, 50]);
                break;
            case 6:
                owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [2, 50]);
                break;
            case 7:
                owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [4, 50]);
                break;
            case 9:
                owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [5, 50]);
                break;
        }
    };

    vm.ConvertToDate = function (jsonDateToConvert) {
        if (jsonDateToConvert == null)
            return "";
        var value = new Date
        (
             parseInt(jsonDateToConvert.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))
        );
        return value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();
    }
}
```

})();

Comment: Take a look at the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) _Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior._

Comment: @AlonEitan the 1st example doesn't use ng-model, shouldn't that work? As the value of test is always true, that comes from the database, i don't understand why the 1st one doesn't get checked then.

Comment: any error shown ? can you share your controller code?

Comment: Don't think it wok that way, maybe `ng-click="vm.eduToEdit.test = !vm.eduToEdit.test"` instead of `ng-checked="vm.eduToEdit.test"`  will work

Comment: is .test a getter function?

Comment: @shaishabroy no errors, i'm able to write out the value, true or false, but it doesn't seem to get set using ng-checked

Comment: can see my answer and visit demo link. it may will help you @paritosh

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/DkxiNuFF91P4pPIKmOPJ?p=preview  The second checkbox toggles both.  This is the same as the demo shown at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: first with checkbox I recommend to use ng-change to trigger the callback on your checkbox to update value in controller. And has I see in your controller code that you use jQuery and do some DOM action inside it. It's not good practice to change DOM behavior inside a controller, you need to create a custom directive for all your DOM effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you will use `ng-checked` then it will act as *one-way* binding means only show checked or unchecked this check box but not changed in controller variable. If you want to change controller variable on change in *dom* then
better to use `ng-model` to checked or unchecked. can try like:

I guess you used `controller as vm` in dom and used `this` in controller.

in html:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.eduToEdit.test">{{vm.eduToEdit.test}}
</body>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.eduToEdit = {};
  vm.eduToEdit.test = true;
});
```

[DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/d4HEporJSKq5hWzdn5bJ?p=preview)

Comment: Please see my update, i have something similar to what you have, i see it running in your demo, not sure what i'm missing though.

Comment: can you share more controller code  and html with `ng-controller` element ?

Comment: are you using `ng-controller="yourCtrl as vm"` ? and some time it happened for digest problem. try to assign in `$timeout` function for `vm.eduToEdit.test = true/false;`

Comment: yes, i'm using ng-controller="EducationController as vm" i tried putting the checkbox right underneath the div with the ng-controller, thinking maybe it's out of scope, but same issue.  i intially thought maybe the true false was coming back as a string, so tried to manually set it, but no luck.

Comment: I believe the reason that it's not working might have to do with Bootstrap, we are using a bootstrap switch and it looks like it does not play well with Angular as it requires Jquery, so will look into the angular-bootstrap project

Answer (score 0):

Click on the second check box to update first, since ng-model is bind with second checkbox whenever you click on it the model value in first checkbox gets updated.

```
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="vm.test" />
    {{vm.test}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.test" />
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kakurala/u06782gv/)